# Block page change

Tags: reactjs, routes, liferay

I have a problem with blocking page changes in the application. The application is written in react and installed in liferay (CMS). It wants to keep the user on the payment intermediary selection screen. Unfortunately, the methods I know do not work properly. Blocking on the "beforeunload" event only blocks the closing of the page or its refresh (I'm only interested in closing the tab, but it is an additional condition). Blocking the website by react router doesn't work properly either. The prompt component works only within the scope of the added page, and no longer works in the navigation created on liferay. This is the same for useHistory (history.block('msg')), because it works just like the prompt component. I also tried to get this effect with other events, unfortunately to no avail. Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Solved https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017880672-Automatic-Single-Page-Applications

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware about Liferay navigation behavior but I can see two resolutions:

1. you could go on using react router to block the transition to another route:

You could find a full example on the official docs (https://reactrouter.com/web/example/preventing-transitions).

```
      <Prompt
        when={isBlocking}
        message={location =>
          `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
        }
      />
```

2. if there are parts of your application not handled by react-router you could rely on some event from history, like the one described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

> A popstate event is dispatched to the window each time the active history entry changes between two history entries for the same document.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work and liferay keeps changing the page

Comment: You need to understand how liferay works and work in a solution from there. Maybe there is some hint on their doc.